# start systemd-nspawn/systemd container on boot

Tags: linux, arch-linux, systemd, container

I've been working with systemd-nspawn and have a couple of containers that I'd like to automatically start at system start.

I'm using arch linux and according to the [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-nspawn) entry, the following code should do the trick

```
# systemctl enable systemd-nspawn@MyContainer.service
# systemctl start systemd-nspawn@MyContainer.service
```

Assuming the container `MyContainer` is in /var/lib/machines and was created with something like:

```
# pacstrap -i -c -d /var/lib/machines/MyContainer base
```

I can start the container with:

```
# sudo systemd-nspawn -b -D /var/lib/machines/MyContainer
```

and

```
# systemctl start systemd-nspawn@MyContainer.service
```

as well as

```
# machinectl start MyContainer
```

but I just can't get the container to start at boot and running `sudo systemctl status systemd-nspawn@MyContainer.service` right after boot doesn't show any errors. Does anyone know what I need to do? Does there maybe need to be another service running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing a little more research, I discovered the problem. It's not that another service needs to be running, but instead another **target**, specifically `machines.target`, so running

```
systemctl enable machines.target
```

in addition to the commands above made it so that `MyContainer` starts at boot.

As a side note, this wasn't immediately clear because when I call

```
systemctl list-units --all --type=target
```

on both of my computers (both running arch linux), `machines.target` is not included in the list. Not sure why, but that was the fix.